# PHP - trying to create an array of checkboxes,

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create an Array from multiple checkboxes that are created via a while loop. the check boxes are named '`to_delete[1]`', '`to_delete[2]`', etc. etc. 
the array statements i've tried are these:

```
$toDelete = array($_POST['to_delete']);
$toDelete = array($_POST['to_delete'][]);
```

to veryify there is an array, i go to print but find it is empty `print_r($toDelete)`. What am i doing wrong? 
the code is below. Yes, i'm doing this procedurally, and then will re-write as OOP. 
big thanks for any help on this!,

```
$showQ = "SELECT * FROM urls";
$result = mysql_query($showQ);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!$result) {
    mysql_error();
   } else {
  echo "<form action='".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."' method='post'>";
  $i=0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<input type='text' class='manId' name='manId[]' value=" . $row['id'] . " />";
echo "<input type='text' class='url' name='url[]' value=" . $row['url'] . " />";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='to_delete[" .$i. "]' /><br/>\n";
$i++;
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='delete' name='submit'  />";
echo "</form>";
}
$toDelete = array($_POST['to_delete[]']);
print_r($toDelete);
```

Ultimately, i want to traverse the array, see which ones are checked and then delete the corresponding row from the table.

Comment: start with print_r($_POST) to see, if anything is transmitted, then update your question.

Comment: What happens when you print_r($_POST["to_delete"]); ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to create an array with the `array()` call, but rather to access one.  `$_POST` will receive input names ending with `[]` as arrays, so the corresponding array keys in `$_POST` will already be arrays.  The way you've written your code, you are assigning a one-element array containing a sub-array from `$_POST`.  Instead, try the following:

```
// Test if $_POST['to_delete'] is set and non-empty
// If it's empty, create an empty array, otherwise assign it to $toDelete
$toDelete = empty($_POST['to_delete']) ? array() : $_POST['to_delete'];
print_$($toDelete);
```